# Spring boot @Configurationproperties large yaml file - nested maps

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot app and have a large  application.yml file which has properties with complex structure(nested maps) that I am trying to bind using @Configurationproperties . 
I am able to bind it when the file is small but as the file size grows it takes a lot of time to load and increases the startup time.
Structure of Yaml:

```
a:
  b:
    - map1: 
       '3000':
        map2:
           '3000': 'true'
           '3010': 'true'
           '4000': 'true'
           '4300': 'true'
           '3300': 'true'
           '3400': 'true'
           '3700': 'true'
           '4600': 'true'
           '4700': 'true'
       '3010':
        map2:
           '3000': 'true'
           '3010': 'true'
           '4000': 'true'
           '4300': 'true'
           '3300': 'true'
           '3400': 'true'
           '3700': 'true'
           '4600': 'true'
           '4700': 'true'
```

I want to decrease the loading time and was wondering if there is a way to lazy load the nested maps. i.e. load the map only when something is requested for?